# Full Calendar modal link with Rails event.id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

OK...
I successfully added full calendar plugin to my Rails 4 application. Everything works as much as the full calendar demo runs.  I am manually creating the jSON events object using loops (not ideal but it works). The calendar displays with the events correctly. When I click an event the appropriate modal appears with extended info on the event.

Now in the modal I want to have a link to the Rails edit form for that event.

I created a custom jQuery var

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
},
defaultDate: '2015-12-12',
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
events: [<%= @caldata %>],


eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
    $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
    $('#editUrl').html("events/" || event.id || "/edit");
    $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
}
});

});
```

The code for the Modal is

```
<a href="#editUrl">edit</a>
```

which no doubt will not render the link. 
Any ideas on how to leave the Modal and go to the Rails edit event form. After updating i can easily return to the full calendar display.

many dankes

Answer (score 0):

Make the id for the link in the modal 'editUrl':

```
<a id="editUrl">Edit</a>
```

Then when setting the path, find the link and set the href property:

```
$('#editUrl').attr('href',"events/" + event.id + "/edit");
```

This is assuming the modal is created beforehand. I'm not sure how your method of creating modals works and your order may be right, but just from looking at it i'd reckon that you should call the .modal() function first to create the modal, then set the properties:

```
$('#fullCalModal').modal();
$('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
$('#modalBody').html(event.description);
$('#editUrl').attr('href',"events/" + event.id + "/edit");
$('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
```